# Can you retract an incorrect flag?

Tags: support, flagging

Due to issues I was having with my mobile phone I accidentally and **incorrectly** flagged a question as containing abusive content.

I cannot see a way of retracting this, and I cannot flag the moderators to say sorry and ignore the flag.

Am I missing something?

**NOTE:** This is through the use of the Android mobile app, not the mobile website browser.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281010

You can retract flags by clicking *flag* again and click *retract flag* at the bottom.  I noticed though that it is not available in the Android app so I had to do it through my mobile browser which was awkward as it wanted to switch to the app, but heyho it is retracted now.

You need to paste the whole question link into the browser address bar to go to the question in the browser.  You can get that in the app by clicking 'share' and copy the address to clipboard.